# Bad retina-image quality while running CCGrid3DAction

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

i'm getting very bad image quality after adding a CCGrid3DAction for example CCLiquid

```
CCLiquid *liquid = [CCLiquid actionWithWaves:2 amplitude:5 grid:ccg(100, 100) duration:5];
[self runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:liquid]];
```

[image: befor]

[image: after]

it looks like the low resolution images or the texture has the half resolution after grabbing the screen, even if amplitude is 0.

this happens only on retina images and "EnableRetinaDisplaySupport = YES;"

the following settings didnt help

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

-- config.lua ( i've set this hi-settings just for testing, )
DefaultTexturePixelFormat = TexturePixelFormat.RGBA8888,
GLViewColorFormat = GLViewColorFormat.RGBA8888,
GLViewDepthFormat = GLViewDepthFormat.Depth24Bit,
GLViewMultiSampling = YES,
GLViewNumberOfSamples = 4,
```

any ideas?

i'm using Kobold2d 2.0.4

UPDATE: tested it with cocos2d 2.1-beta4 but get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is projection mode. By default cocos2d 2.0 uses 2D projection but for 3D actions you'll have to use 3D projection. Change that in AppDelegate by calling CCDirector's setProjection method.

Comment: didnt help. i've added 2 images to see whats happend. for me it seems like the half the resolution.

Comment: hmm perhaps the "grid" actions either don't support Retina resolutions, or lower the resolution on purpose for performance reasons. The screenshot looks like it's even less than standard resolution.

Comment: so you think there is no solution? or should i hack a GridAction by myself ;o)

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a bug based on previous bugs relating to this exact type of issue with retina displays. Submit a bug report. The behavior you are experiencing is not the intended behavior so even if you found a workaround this should still be reported. http://cocos2d-central.com/topic/513-read-me-how-to-report-issues-or-request-features/